# How to write Java certificate file as a Json string field?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to generate a JSON file with all the required information I need to transfer and do further operations on an another system. One of the fields is the java certificate. Since I just need to replicate the contents of the files as it is on the another system I thought reading the contents directly and then writing to a file would work. But while loading the newly written file I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
```

What would be the correct approach of doing this?

Currently, for reading the original certificate I am using:

```
FileUtils.readFileToString(originalTrustFile);
```

to write a new file I am using:

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(trustFile, trustJsonContent.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite idea of having keystore embedded in some JSON file looks strange to me, below you can find one of correct ways of putting/retrieving binary data into/from JSON field as String.

```
import java.util.Base64; //for Java 8
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

//encode to Base64
byte[] binaryFileBytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(originalTrustFile);
String jsonFieldValue = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(binaryFileBytes);

//decode from Base64     
String jsonFieldValue = ... //obtain from your JSON
byte[] binaryFileBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(jsonFieldValue);
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(trustFile, binaryFileBytes);
```

Opposing to your initial approach, above will produce guaranteed safe String which will not interfere with JSON reserved symbols and thus will not be corrupted upon escaping or deserialization

**Note 1**: For Java 7 and earlier you need apache commons-codec library in your classpath, and use quite similar `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`. Consult with [javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) on how it should be used, see methods `encodeBase64String(byte[])` and `decodeBase64(String)`

**Note 2**: [Base64 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) produces +33% more overhead to initial size of binary data, so it must be used with caution for fairly big files

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggested approach. I was just reading that you could convert default java certificates format to .pem format as well. I'll be reading more about it. Not sure if pem format can contain both certificate and private key, or I'll have to extract them and put them as separate fields in the json file to reconstruct the certificate later.

Comment: According to [RFC7468](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7468), textual representation of .pem must contain 2 enclosing lines (`---Begin ... ---` and  `--- End ... ----`) with base64 content in the middle. Seems to let .pem be a correct JSON field value, you should take care of escaping those 2 newline characters, and unescape them on deserialization. That gives more understandable JSON (human can easily extract pem cert from JSON and work with it further) on the one hand, paid by additional processing effort on the other. Are you going to add your PEM option as an answer here?

Comment: For now, I was able to move forward in my task by just converting everything to Base64 encoded string ... And then on the other system decoding the string as a byte array and writing it to a file. Thanks!